# Flip only one DIV and not all of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Both the divs that have same class names are flipping if you hover only one. Just the div that hovered should flip and not all that have the same class name. JQuery code needs to be tweaked rest is all good. So only active div needs to be changed and not all classes with the same name.

```
<div class="card col-lg-2 col-md-2 block1 ">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="cardFront">
            <br>    
            <h1>Front Content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="cardBack">BACK CONTENT</div>
    </div> 
</div>

<div class="card col-lg-2 col-md-2 block2 ">
    <div class="content div2">
        <div class="cardFront">
            <br>    
            <h1>Front Content</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="cardBack">BACK CONTENT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
    perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -o-perspective: 1000px;
    -ms-perspective: 1000px;
    width:200px;
    height:180px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 0 20px 28px; 
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;

}

.card .content {
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-out;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    /* content backface is visible so that static content still appears */
    backface-visibility: visible;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -moz-backface-visibility: visible;
    -o-backface-visibility: visible;
    -ms-backface-visibility: visible;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
.card.applyflip .content {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}


.card .content .cardStatic {
    /* Half way through the card flip, rotate static content to 0 degrees */
    transition: 0s linear 0.17s;
    -webkit-transition: 0s linear 0.17s;
    -moz-transition: 0s linear 0.17s;
    -o-transition: 0s linear 0.17s;
    -ms-transition: 0s linear 0.17s;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);

    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.card.applyflip .content .cardStatic {
    /* Half way through the card flip, rotate static content to -180 degrees -- to negate the flip and unmirror the static content */
    transition: 0s linear 0.17s;
    -webkit-transition: 0s linear 0.17s;
    -moz-transition: 0s linear 0.17s;
    -o-transition: 0s linear 0.17s;
    -ms-transition: 0s linear 0.17s;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card .content .cardFront {
background-image:url('../images/back10.png'); 
background-color: #961B1D; 
}

.card .content .cardBack {
background-color: #961B1D; 

}

.card .content .cardFront, .card .content .cardBack {
    /* Backface visibility works great for all but IE. As such, we mark the backface visible in IE and manage visibility ourselves */
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

}
.card .content .cardFront, .card.applyflip .content .cardFront {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.card .content .cardBack, .card.applyflip .content .cardBack {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card .content .cardFront, .card.applyflip .content .cardBack {
    /* IE Hack. Halfway through the card flip, set visibility. Keep other browsers visible throughout the card flip. */
    animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
    -webkit-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
    -moz-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
    -o-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
    -ms-animation: donothing 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.17s;
    visibility: visible;
}
.card.applyflip .content .cardFront, .card .content .cardBack {
    /* IE Hack. Halfway through the card flip, set visibility. Keep other browsers visible throughout the card flip. */
    animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
    -webkit-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
    -moz-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
    -o-animation: stayvisible 0.5s both;
    -ms-animation: donothing 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.17s;
    visibility: hidden;
}
@keyframes stayvisible { from { visibility: visible; } to { visibility: visible; } }
@-webkit-keyframes stayvisible { from { visibility: visible; } to { visibility: visible; } }
@-moz-keyframes stayvisible { from { visibility: visible; } to { visibility: visible; } }
@-o-keyframes stayvisible { from { visibility: visible; } to { visibility: visible; } }
@-ms-keyframes donothing { 0% { } 100% { } }
```

JS:

```
$('.card').hover(function(){
    $('.card').toggleClass('applyflip');
    }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `$('.card')` by `$(this)` to get the current element

```
$('.card').hover(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('applyflip');
});
```

And you don't need and shouldn't `bind(this)`. `jQuery` does that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the "this" in your function to say which one you mean.

```
$('.card').on("hover", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('applyflip');
});
```